# Searching for a field in AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elasticsearch

After indexing ddb records into ElasticSearch, when doing a simple search `/_search?q=test`, I see the hits shown like this

```
"hits": [
            {
                // ignore other fields ...
                "_id": "z0YdS3I",
                "_source": {
                    "M": {
                        "name": {
                            "S": "test name"
                        },
                        "age": {
                            "N": "18"
                        },
                        // ignore other fields ...
                    }
                }
            },
            ....
        ]
```

However, when I search for a specific field, e.g. `/_search?q=name:test`, I get zero hits. This happens with every field.

```
"hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
```

So instead I have to search like this `_search?q=M.name.S=test`, which is a bit cumbersome. Just wonder if there's a cleaner way to search for a field? Maybe I'm missing some configuration during indexing step?

Comment: the "test" text is inside `M.name.S` and not just under field `name` . why is that ?  is that what you desire ? or some problem while indexing the data ?

Comment: It was not what I intended. When adding data to ES, if I add a normal object, I'll get 400 "'object mapping for [name] tried to parse field [name] as object, but found a concrete value'". ES was expecting input in that format. So instead I have to search for M.name.S which a bit cumbersome.

Comment: so you could try to first define mappings for your index as per your requirement . like - "name":"text", "age":ïnteger" etc .  then check if that got applied properly using '/_mapping' API - once you see the datatypes are proper then start indexing data into Elasticsearch.

Comment: ah, I see. that could be the reason. I didn't define mapping before adding data to ES. But one problem is that since DDB table can change, it's hard to define the mapping in advance. But I think you're right. Feel free to post the answer, so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

First define mappings for your index as per your requirement . like -

```
"name":"text", 
"age":"integer"
.
.
etc
```

Then check if that got applied properly using `/_mapping API` - once you see the datatypes are applied as you desire then start indexing data.

Details of mappings => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: +1 Thanks @sowjany-r-hhat, but since the ddb documents can change (attributes can be added and be missing), this approach is not suitable in my case. I also found out AWS provided a library to convert DDB document to normal JS object. I posted an answer with details.

Comment: @chepukha so you are syncing Dynamo data to ES . cool ! so in future if i have the same usecase of pulling data from dynamo n loading it to ES i should be using `dynamo-converter` . my current case is i dump data to ES using python - where i first define mapping - then index it. you might find this link also useful (for general ES knowledge) => https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

I found out I could use [DynamoDB Converter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html) provided by AWS SDK to convert back and forth between Javascript object and its equivalent DDB AttributeValue type. That way I can index a document in the write mapping and access it with the normal fields.